# Php - Mysql stored procedure not returning data

Tags: php, mysql, json, stored-procedures

I am working in a project that involves Php - Mysql.  I have the following stored procedure in MySQL:
`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alumnos_get_alumno(IN ci INT UNSIGNED)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   SELECT idalumnos, CONVERT(primer_nombre USING utf8) AS primer_nombre, 
          CONVERT(segundo_nombre USING utf8) AS segundo_nombre, 
          CONVERT(tercer_nombre USING utf8) AS tercer_nombre, 
          CONVERT(primer_apellido USING utf8) AS primer_apellido, 
          CONVERT(segundo_apellido USING utf8) AS segundo_apellido, 
          fecha_nac, estado_actual 
     FROM alumnos WHERE idalumnos = ci;
END`
```

And I call it from the following Php script:

```
$config= parse_ini_file("../config/cole.ini");
$connect= mysqli_connect("localhost", $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']) or die("NO DB Connection");

$getparams = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET);
$query = "CALL alumnos_get_alumno(".$getparams['c'].")";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$cuantos = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($cuantos != 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $output = json_encode($row);
    }
} else {
    $output = 0;
}
echo $output;
```

Now, the problem is that when executing the Php script, I get an empty response.

I tried debugging the script execution with Firebug, and actually seen that the procedure DOES return data (tried with `print_r()` and got back the array with the data), but when I try to store said data in the `$output` variable using `json_encode()`, it "disappears" so to speak.

I have several other procedures that are exactly the same thing just changing the table name, and those do work without any problems.

**EDIT**: I also checked the log in `/var/log/apache2/err.log` to see if there were any errors reported by the server, but nothing of the sorts appears.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

To store response you need to create an array assing your while loop value to that array then use `json_encode`

```
$output = array();
if ($cuantos != 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    $output[] = 0;
}

$output = json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried what you suggested, but get an empty Array as response.  The result of `print_r($row)` is: Array ( [idalumnos] => 1 [primer_nombre] => JOHNNY [segundo_nombre] => B [tercer_nombre] =>  [primer_apellido] => GOODE [segundo_apellido] => DUDE [fecha_nac] => 1999-10-07 [estado_actual] => A )

Comment: Ahh my bad use `$output[] = $row;` inside while loop !! check updated answer!!

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, but still the same result.  Now, one thing that I found: When executing as root (giving root credentials instead of loading them from the config file), the query does work.  But again, is specifically THAT procedure that has the behaviour.

Comment: After much trying I added the following to the Php script:

`json_last_error_msg()`

As it turns out, some of the first records that were being retrieved were utf8-malformed, so, I changed the loop to:

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push( $salida,
                array(
                    utf8_encode($row['idalumnos']), ... );
    }

This way, the strings were properly encoded before being pushed into the array.  And, it worked.